# Calculting colours based on contrast

Tags: colors, selection

I hI have a website that runs several colour themes. I want to change the text select colour based on the colour theme.

```
p::selection,  
li::selection,  
div::selection{  
  background-color: #hex;  
  color: #ffffff;  
}
```

I'm also using the -moz and -o prefixes.

For the colour theme where I'm using #274569 the default colour of #339aff is acceptable and I've calculated the contrast. What I want to do is work out how to calculate the colour from another (#148545 for example) if I have the contrast.
There is no shortage of resources to the web to calculate the contrast of two colours but I'm after doing it the other way round, unless there a better way of choosing the colour.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How did you calculate the contrast?

Comment: I used this site:https://www.joedolson.com/tools/color-contrast.php?type=hex&color=274569&color2=339aff

Comment: Given ColourA, there are any number of colours that match or exceed some nominal contrast - and they will not necessarily sit pleasingly side-by-side.

Comment: I realise that but I can't think of any other way to work out the colour. I can see which ones work and change the others.